# In SAP HANA how can I generate a range of numbers, eg from 1 to 10?

Tags: hana

In SAP HANA I wish to have a view which has a range of number from 1 to 10, or 1 to n where n is any number. So when I select from the view I can select n records to get the first n records from the range.

I was able to create a table with 1000 rows with a ID that increment's by using this stored procedure. Is there an easier way?

```
DROP PROCEDURE "DEMO_PROC";
CREATE PROCEDURE "DEMO_PROC"(
         IN    ID    INTEGER )
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT AS
/*********BEGIN PROCEDURE SCRIPT ************/
BEGIN
DECLARE
         START_ID INTEGER;
DROP TABLE TEST_TABLE;
CREATE COLUMN TABLE "TEST_TABLE" (ID INTEGER, NAME VARCHAR(10));
START_ID := 0;
WHILE START_ID < 1000 DO
  START_ID := START_ID + 1;
  INSERT INTO "TEST_TABLE" VALUES(:START_ID, '');
 END WHILE;
END;

CALL "DEMO_PROC"(1);

SELECT * FROM "TEST_TABLE";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a generator is the preferred way:

```
INSERT INTO "TEST_TABLE" 
    SELECT GENERATED_PERIOD_START as ID, '' as NAME
    FROM SERIES_GENERATE_INTEGER(1,1,1001);
```

is much easier and faster.

Answer (score 2):

I think `for loop` is easier than `while`.

```
FOR START_ID IN 1..1000 DO
INSERT INTO "TEST_TABLE" VALUES(START_ID,'');
END FOR;
```